# How to do a Pug for loop with AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, pug

I am working on a Tinder clone web project for school using Node.js, Express, and Pug that needs to return potential matches with a priority on either distance from the current user or similar interests shared with the current user. When the user first enters their page of potential matches I have the site automatically show the user the best possible matches based on a distance of 5km from their current position. I am sending to the page I render an Array of matches called users and a size of that array called userslen that I pulled from my database in my node file. I then proceed to show the potential matches on the page using this pug for loop:

```
div(class='container', id='searchResults') <!-- SEARCH RESULTS -->
      div(class='row')
      - for (var i = 0; i < userslen; i++) {
        div(class='col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 usertop')
          div(class='row')
            div(class='col-lg-12 col-md-12')
              a(href='/users/' + users[i].username)
                h1=users[i].username
                  - if (users[i].liked == true) {
                  span(id='youlikeglyph', class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok")
                  - } else if (users[i].disliked == true) {
                  span(id='youdislikeglyph', class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove")
                  - } else {

                  - }
          div(class='row')
            div(class='col-lg-12 col-md-12')
              img(id='viewerphoto1', class='userpagephoto', src='/static/uploads/' + users[i].filename)
          div(class='row')
            - if (users[i].liked == false && users[i].disliked == false) {
            div(class='btn-group')
              button(id='dislike' + i, class='btn btn-danger btn-lg')
                |Dislike
              button(id='like' + i, class='btn btn-success btn-lg')
                |   Like
            - } else if (users[i].liked == false && users[i].disliked == true) {
            button(id='like' + i, class='btn btn-success btn-lg')
              |Like
            - } else if (users[i].liked == true && users[i].disliked == false) {
            button(id='dislike' + i, class='btn btn-danger btn-lg')
              |Dislike
            - } else {

            - }
          div(class='row')
            div(class='col-lg-4 col-md-4')
              h5="Distance"
              h4=users[i].distance + "km"
            div(class='col-lg-4 col-md-4')
              h5="Same Tags"
              h4=users[i].cTags
            div(class='col-lg-4 col-md-4')
              h5="Popularity"
              h4=users[i].popularity
      - }
```

There are two buttons at the top of my page (not shown in the above code) that allow a user to choose to search based on distance or based on tags with a min and max distance/tags-in-common input. When they click on the button of their choice with the min max they have entered I send the data through AJAX to a post that then returns a new array of potential matches based on this new data. Is there a way to make the same for loop I have in the above code but using jQuery once my AJAX response is a success? If there is, what is the best way to go about it? Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot go back to Jade/Pug once you're on the client. Jade is a templating engine that works on Node. Once you're on the client, it doesn't exist anymore.

You'll need to just loop over your HTML in jQuery, and won't be able to use Jade for this.

Another option is to use one of the client side templating frameworks like `Underscore templates`/`Handlebars`/`Moustache JS` etc.

Using these, you can handle the looping much more elegantly than you can using jQuery, but of course, that really is a call you should take, because this would mean additional payload over the wire.

With one of the templating frameworks, you can define your template in Jade and then reuse it for your iterations

Comment: Thank you for your response! I'm aware that I can't go back to the pug file once I'm on the client side but I'm wondering how to make the same for loop in jquery. Is there a best practice for doing the loop in jquery? I saw dom manipulation with append() and similar functions as well as doing innerHtml or html() after using empty() on my container. The problem with the html() is it seems like it would just be an insanely long string. Is there something you suggest?

Comment: Pseudo code:

1. `$.get()`
2. within your `.success()` function, run a `$.each()`
3. `element.append()` within your loop

This the standard method to populate